# render a null value with a select/drop-down on blade

Tags: forms, laravel, drop-down-menu, laravel-blade

From the "Form" laravelcollective manual:

> Generating a Drop-Down List With an Empty Placeholder This will create an "option" element with no value as the very first option of
>   your drop-down.
>
> echo Form::select('size', ['L' => 'Large', 'S' => 'Small'], null,
>   ['placeholder' => 'Pick a size...']);

My code on a blade page:

```
{{ Form::select('company_id', $companies->pluck('name','id'), null , ['id'=>'company_id','class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

It render:

```
<select id="company_id" class="form-control" name="company_id">
     <option value="1">azienda1</option>
     <option value="2">azienda2</option>
</select>
```

why there is no null value? where im wrong?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Why not use in select `<option value=""></option>`

Comment: because the "option" are generated by the function! or there is a way to force it on the code?

Comment: Are you wanting to add an empty placeholder?

Comment: @RossWilson yes like the manual said! or I wrong something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `null` value in the example is for setting the initial value not for setting the placeholder.

The manual says `['placeholder' => 'Pick a size...'])` for a placeholder.

To add an empty placeholder you should be able to do:

```
{{ Form::select('company_id', $companies->pluck('name','id'), null , ['id'=>'company_id','class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => '']) }}
```

Comment: it works thanks a lot... the gap with my not perfect eng make all so hard!

Comment: ok it works... but how can select again the empty value after a choice? if I select a value the blank place holder disappear and the tag is setted like: <option selected="selected" disabled="disabled" hidden="hidden" value="">All the companies</option>

Comment: Yes, this the way a select placeholder works. The idea is that you only show it when there isn't a value hasn't been set. To have an empty option that you can select again you would need to add that to the main values i.e. `$companies->pluck('name', 'id')->prepend('', '')` and then change `null` to `''`.